Minimum number of operations for array of numbers to all equal one number
You have one array of numbers, for example [2, 5, 1]. You have a second array of numbers, for example [8, 4, 3]. For each of the numbers in the second array, how many operations would it take to make the first array all equal that number? You can only increment or decrement by 1 at a time.
To get to 8, it would take (8-2)+(8-5)+(8-1)=16 operations. 
To get to 4, it would take (4-2)+(5-4)+(4-1)=6 operations. 
To get to 3, it would take (3-2)+(5-3)+(3-1)=5 operations. 
So the answer would be [16, 6, 5].

I was able to do this in one line:
answer = [sum(abs(x-y) for x in a1) for y in a2]

But this wasn't fast enough when the arrays can have up to 105 items. How would I be able to do this faster?

Same approach as the others (sort, use bisect to split into the i smaller and the n-i larger values, and look up their sums with precomputed prefix sums), just less code:
from itertools import accumulate
from bisect import bisect

def solve(a1, a2):
    a1.sort()
    p1 = 0, *accumulate(a1)
    n = len(a1)
    total = p1[-1]
    return [
        (i*y - p1[i]) + (total-p1[i] - (n-i)*y)
        for y in a2
        for i in [bisect(a1, y)]
    ]

Attempt This Online!
The expression in the list comprehension could be "optimized" to (2*i-n)*y + total-2*p1[i], but I can't make sense of that and prefer the longer version where I compute the costs for the i smaller values and the n-i larger values separately.

Well , I have a solution for this . Firstly, Sort the First array because Here position of the value of the first array doesn’t matter .
Secondly, Calculate prefix sum of the sorted array .
Thirdly, For every value of the second array Do binary search on the first sorted array . And find the lower bound of the Value . Then from prefix sum you can calculate how much you need to increase before the value and how much you can decrease after the value .
Overall time complexity will be o(n*log(n)) .
I hope it will pass .

As already answered, you can solve this with some preprocessing and binary search.
The preprocessing could consist of sorting a1 and then collecting the number of operations for when the values occur in a1, separated in the counts for the lesser values in a1, and the counts for the greater values in a1. Then you can use a kind of interpolation to calculate the exact total for any given value, using binary search:
from bisect import bisect_left

def runningsums(a):
    total = 0
    yield 0
    yield from (total := total + abs(curr - prev) * (i + 1) 
                for i, (prev, curr) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:])))
  
def solve(a1, a2):
    # preprocessing
    a1.sort()
    before = list(runningsums(a1))
    after  = list(runningsums(a1[::-1]))[::-1]
    n = len(a1)
    # collect results
    result = []
    for val in a2:
        i = bisect_left(a1, val)
        total = 0
        if i < n:
            total += (a1[i] - val) * (n-i) + after[i]
        if i > 0:
            total += (val - a1[i-1]) * i + before[i-1]
        result.append(total)

    return result


The brute force approaches below all take about 2/3 of the time the original approach took in Python 3.12. These are not algorithmic improvements, just constructs that happen to work faster due to CPython's implementation details.
from itertools import starmap, batched, repeat, product

matrix = map(abs, starmap(sub, product(a2, a1)))
ans1 = list(map(sum, batched(matrix, len(a1))))

ans2 = [sum(map(abs, starmap(sub, zip(a1, repeat(y))))) for y in a2]

ans3 = list(map(lambda y: sum(map(abs, starmap(sub, zip(a1, repeat(y))))), a2))

Of course, doing all this in numpy will take next to no time - as it well should.
And algorithmic improvements matter more than small changes in the constant in front of N^2.
The only improvement I can think of to [the excellent answer][2] is to calculate running sums using faster C functions rather than Python code. It's still Python, but under the hood it's all C. In Python 3.12, this is about twice as fast as the original implementation:
def runningsums(a):
    absdiffs = map(abs, map(sub, a, a[1:]))
    products = starmap(mul, enumerate(absdiffs, 1))
    return accumulate(products, initial=0)

